# .htaccess does not redirect

Tags: php, regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am creating a MVC structure for my php web application.
It's a Windows 8.1 system, running xampp.
The .htaccess file does not work correctly. It is located here:

```
C:\xampp\htdocs\hmb
```

When I open this url in firefox:

```
http://localhost/hmb/test
```

I want this to be processed:

```
http://localhost/hmb/index.php?url=page
```

But I get an error (404).

This is my .htaccess files content:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]
```

*$_GET['url']* in index.php just does not exist.
I configured the httpd.conf file.
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: If the query parameter "url" doesn't exist in your code (or isn't used in your router), then why do you use it in `.htaccess` in the first place? Besides, this has been asked a trillion times here. And if you can't find an appropriate question/answer, look at the `.htaccess` files provided by [Joomla](http://joomla.org/), [wordpress](http://wordpress.org/), [symfony2](http://symfony.com/), …

Comment: @nietonfir When I say it does not exist, I mean, of course, it's not been passed as a parameter. Everything else wouldn't make sense. I have this code from a popular youtube video, called "PHP: Create Your Own MVC (Part 1)", so I don't think it's wrong. If you know a helpful answer, don't hesitate to post it.

Comment: @ChristophBühler yeah .. well .. that video is terrible. And completely wrong. MVC is not about directory structure or pretty URLs. The MVC pattern defines constraints for information flow between application layers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Place this code in `/hmb/.htaccess`:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /hmb/

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
RewriteRule ^index.php/(.+)$ index.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]
```

Comment: Thank you for answering. It still doesn't work. I am on Windows and working with xampp. Could this be the problem?

Comment: Always provide as much details as possible regarding your problem. What URL did you enter in bowser and what error did you get?

Comment: @ChristophBühler path info must be accepted. See [`AcceptPathInfo`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#acceptpathinfo)

Answer (score 0):

Use this RewriteCond to catch what comes after the initial page

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(.*)$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ hmb/index.php?url=$1 [L]
```